# Cinema4d model in XNA skinned model texture bluring

Tags: model, xna, cinema-4d

http://i685.photobucket.com/albums/vv212/com268/C81CBAA9C5C6C74C_zps63f9d41b.png

here is my image

I have problem with XNA. I've made my model by using Cinema 4D and exported to .fbx format

I have no problem with example "dude.fbx" but when I load my image

it is blured. and down-scaled.

I followed few tutorials such as change "sampling" setting to none.

or turning off "anti aliasing" option. but all of them didn't work.

Should I use other 3D Modeller or am I getting something wrong here?